# what is the difference between pthreadID and LWPID?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have a multithread C++ program. I understand that each process has a pid and multiple threads have unique tid's . LWPid's are kernal level ids for the threads that process owns and pthreadId's are user level identifiers.
i tried to trace my program i could see, two traces with same pthreadId but different lwpid, how is this possible? (i am trying to run this program on Linux)

```
20170807 04:48:01.743 [pid:32174,pthreadId:139630838007552,lwpId:589][work] starter function
20170807 04:48:01.753 [pid:32174,pthreadId:139630838007552,lwpId:590][work] starter function
```

Comment: Post your source code.

Comment: The pthread ID was re-used. Not much mystery there.